# extraer elementos de dos array y pasarlo a otros JS

Tags: javascript, array

como puedo extraer elementos de dos array y pasarlo a otro array
con el metodo `slice` puedo extrear elementos de un array pero no se como le puedo pasar como parametro el segundo array
mi codigo

```
 function mifuncion(persona1, persona2) {
  var cosas_en_comun = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < persona1.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < persona2.length; j++) {
       if(persona1[i] === persona2[j]){
         
       }
    }
  }
    return cosas_en_comun;
}
```

Comment: Agrega tus arrays y describe mejor por favor ¿de esos arrays qué elementos debe extraer? y finalmente qué fallo da este código

Comment: por el nombre cosas_en_comun asumo que quieres obtener los elementos que ambos arrays tienen en comun, pero lo mejor es que especifiques, y pongas los 2 arrays que tienes y el array que deseas obtener como ejemplo.

Comment: SI la activades consiste en mostrar la cosas en común  entre una persona y la  persona1 = ['leer', 'comer', 'pasear', 'dormir', 'jugar']
  //     persona2 = ['comer', 'dormir', 'futbol']

Comment: si es un array de strings te servirá la respuesta que deje debajo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si quieres obtener los elementos que 2 arrays tienen en comun, puedes usar un filter junto con indexOf:

```
var x = ['IdA', 'idB', 'IdC', 'IdD', 'IdE'];
var y = ['idB', 'IdE', 'IdF'];

var z = x.filter(function(val) {
  return y.indexOf(val) != -1;
});

console.log(z); // array con intersecciones
```

respuesta obtenida de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343295/compare-two-arrays-and-return-duplicate-values/26343472